# Firebase Cloud Function. Access variable from environment file got undefined when deploy functions

Tags: firebase, deployment, google-cloud-functions

Currently, I config environment variables based on [link](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/config-env?gen=2nd).
I have 2 file was named like: .env.[*namespace_project_1] and .env.[*namespace_project_2] both file is inside functions folder and just simple defined the region for each project.
Script from package.json is: "firebase use *namespace_project_1 && firebase deploy --only functions" and I got this logged: "Loaded environment variables from .env.*namespace_project_1" then got the error message: "Error: HTTP Error: 403, Permission denied on 'locations/undefined' (or it may not exist)"
Kinda like I just got the misunderstanding somewhere, please correct me if I wrong

I try to run the script: "firebase use *namespace_project_1 && firebase deploy --only functions" and expected that script will give me the region of project_1, but I got the error of undefined.